# google charts ChartRangeFilter learn range start,end values before setting

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, data-visualization

I'm using google charts and specifically [chartrangefilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) Here You can move your range freely to any date. **BUT** when I move my date before year 100 it messed up. 
Below you can see that my range is from year 108 to year 667 [image]

When I move starting value of the range to smaller than year 100, it **magically** jumps to **1993**. WHY IS THAT?
[image]

I want to prevent this. So is there a way to know which value will it will set when I moved my range?

Evidence to the google charts messes up when it goes to the left of year 100. I moved my range to the left of 100 slightly.
[image: console logs when I moved the range to left]

Comment: I think it is not related with code. Also my code file is too big, mostly unrelated with here

Comment: you have a better chance of getting an answer if we can see the problem in action...